# how to explain this? A "new"-ed array is not initialized...?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I met something strange : an array "new"-ed in heap with random values...

I did a test with codes below:

```
class Solution_046 {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> permute(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>> rst;
        int sz = nums.size();
        if(sz)
        {
            vector<int> group;
            int* inuse = new int[sz];
            cout<<"--------- inuse ------------"<<endl;
            for(int ii=0; ii<sz; ++ii)
                //inuse[ii]=0, cout<<inuse[ii]<<", ";
                cout<<inuse[ii]<<",, ";
            cout<<endl;

            //......
        }
        return rst;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Solution_046 s046;
    vector<int> vv;
    vv.push_back(1);
    vv.push_back(2);
    vv.push_back(3);
    vv.push_back(4);
    vv.push_back(5);
    vv.push_back(6);
    vv.push_back(7);
    vector< vector<int> > rst = s046.permute(vv);
    return 0;
}
```

If I disable one or two lines of those "vv.push_back(...)", then the result printed will include some random value instead of all zeros:

```
$ ./nc (with all 7 lines)
--------- inuse ------------
0,, 0,, 0,, 0,, 0,, 0,, 0,, 

$ ./nc (disalbed one line)
--------- inuse ------------
29339680,, 0,, 4,, 5,, 0,, 0,, 

$ ./nc (disabled two lines)
--------- inuse ------------
26095648,, 0,, 5,, 6,, 0,, 

$ ./nc (disabled three lines)
--------- inuse ------------
0,, 0,, 0,, 0,, 

$ ./nc (disabled four lines)
--------- inuse ------------
0,, 0,, 0,, 0,, 

$ ./nc (disabled five lines)
--------- inuse ------------
0,, 0,,

$ ./nc (disabled six lines)
--------- inuse ------------
0,,
```

What happened while disabling one or two lines, why there are non-zero values in the "new"-ed array?

Comment: Please note that disabling or enabling lines had no bearing on the fact that `new` does not initialize memory for POD types.

Answer (score 7):

```
int* inuse = new int[sz];
```

This call will allocate memory for the `int` array, but it won't value-initialize the contents. If you want to initialize with zeros, use this syntax:

```
int* inuse = new int[sz]();
int* inuse = new int[sz]{}; //c++11
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this happen on only "int"?

Comment: @DaveXu: No, it's standard behaviour for all POD (plain old data) types (class types get their constructor run for them). `malloc()` does not zero-initialize either, so why do you expect `new` to do so?

Comment: It's to do with whether or not `T` is a POD type or not. Read up on [default-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) vs. [value-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Comment: Yes, malloc doesn't do that. Still curious, for "new", is it because "int" is not an object and there is no constructor to be called therefore no initialization happens?

Comment: It's because `int` is not a class type.

Comment: @TartanLlama: Thanks for the links, very helpful~!

Answer (score 3):

Initialisation to zero is an arbitrary, normally unnecessary, and a not particularly cheap overhead. So the language doesn't do it by default.

Using an array element that has not been initialised is undefined behaviour in C++.

You can *force* zero initialisation by using `{}` after the `new`: `new int[sz]{};`. Formally that sets the *memory* block to zeros.

Comment: Agreed that the language doesn't do it because it's an overhead. However that's not nearly as much as the overhead trying to debug the resultant mess when the initialisation doesn't initialise quite enough

Comment: @TomTanner: And be *really* careful before you suggest *everybody* should *always* zero-initialize *everything*. Blanket statements like that have led to truly dismal C/C++ code in the past...

Comment: Good debuggers can trap uninitialised variables. Setting them to zero defeats that. So @TomTanner: I don't think I could disagree more.

Comment: @JorenHeit the point is that 'normally unnecessary' is an overstatement. There are cases where it's unnecessary and there are cases where it isn't